# How to add keys and values to a dict in a loop?

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to create a dict that holds name,position and number for each player for each team. But when trying to create the final dictionary `players[team_name] =dict(zip(number,name,position))` it throws an error (see below). I can't seem to get it right, any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here would be highly appreciated. Many thanks,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
from lxml import html


clubs_url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/clubs'
parent_url = clubs_url.rsplit('/', 1)[0]
data = requests.get(clubs_url).text
html = soup(data, 'html.parser')

team_name = []
team_link = []

for ul in html.find_all('ul', {'class': 'block-list-5 block-list-3-m block-list-1-s block-list-1-xs block-list-padding dataContainer'}):
    for a in ul.find_all('a'):
        team_name.append(str(a.h4).split('>', 1)[1].split('<')[0])
        team_link.append(parent_url+a['href'])
team_link = [item.replace('overview', 'squad') for item in team_link]
team = dict(zip(team_name, team_link))

data = {}
players = {}

for team_name, team_link in team.items():
    player_page = requests.get(team_link)
    cont = soup(player_page.content, 'lxml')
    clud_ele = cont.find_all('span', attrs={'class' : 'playerCardInfo'})
    for i in clud_ele:
        v_number = [100 if v == "-" else v.get_text(strip=True) for v in i.select('span.number')]
        v_name = [v.get_text(strip=True) for v in i.select('h4.name')]
        v_position = [v.get_text(strip=True) for v in i.select('span.position')]
        key_number = [key for element in i.select('span.number') for key in element['class']]
        key_name = [key for element in i.select('h4.name') for key in element['class']]
        key_position = [key for element in i.select('span.position') for key in element['class']]
        number = dict(zip(key_number,v_number))
        name = dict(zip(key_name,v_name))
        position = dict(zip(key_position,v_name))
        players[team_name] = dict(zip(number,name,position))

---> 21         players[team_name] = dict(zip(number,name,position))
     22 
     23 

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
```

Comment: why you need `v_number`but also `key_number` ? it is not enough only `v_number `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in your code. The one causing the error is that you are trying to instantiate a dictionary with a 3-items tuple in list which is not possible. See [the dict doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict) for details.

---

That said, I would suggest to rework the whole nested loop.

First, you have in `clud_ele` a list of player info, each player info concerns only one player and provides only one position, only one name and only one number. So there is no need to store those informations in lists, you could use simple variables:

```py
for player_info in clud_ele:
    number = player_info.select('span.number')[0].get_text(strip=True)
    if number == '-':
        number = 100
    name = player_info.select('h4.name')[0].get_text(strip=True)
    position = player_info.select('span.position')[0].get_text(strip=True)
```

Here, usage of `select` method returns a list but since you know that the list contains only one item, it's ok to get this item to call `get_text` on. But you could check that the `player_info.select('span.number')` length is actually 1 before continuing to work if you want to be sure...

This way, you get scalar data type which will be much easier to manipulate.
Also note that I renamed the `i` to `player_info` which is much more explicit.

Then you can easily add your player data to your `players` dict:

```py
players[team_name].append({'name': name,
                           'position': position
                           'number': number})
```

This assume that you create the `players[team_name]` before the nested loop with `players[team_name] = []`.

*Edit: as stated in the [@kederrac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019577/2696355), usage of a `defaultdict` is a smart and convenient way to avoid the manual creation of each `players[team_name]` list*

Finally, this will give you:

- a dictionary containing values for `name`, `position` and `number` keys for each player
- a team list containg player dictionaries for each team
- a players dictionary associating a team list for each `team_name`

---

It is the data structure you seems to want, but other structures are possible. Remember to think about your data structure to make it logical AND easily manipulable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the flaws and giving so many valuable tips and pointing to docs, thank you for taking your time to write this up!

Comment: @MisterButter You're welcome. Note the usage of `defaultdict` in the @kederrac 's solution: it is a smart way to avoid the  `players[team_name] = []` intialisation before the nested loop, and I would recommand to use it.

Answer (score 1):

you can't instantiate a `dict` with 3 arguments, the problem is the fact that you have 3 variables in the `zip`: `zip(number, name, position)` with which  you want to instantiate a `dict`, you should give only 2 arguments at a time, the key and the value

I've rewritten your las part of the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = {}
players = defaultdict(list)

for team_name, team_link in team.items():
    player_page = requests.get(team_link)
    cont = soup(player_page.text, 'lxml')
    clud_ele = cont.find_all('span', attrs={'class' : 'playerCardInfo'})
    for i in clud_ele:
        num = i.select('span.number')[0].get_text(strip=True)
        number = 100 if num == '-' else num
        name = i.select('h4.name')[0].get_text(strip=True)
        position = i.select('span.position')[0].get_text(strip=True)
        players[team_name].append({'number': number, 'position': position, 'name': name})
```

**output:**

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'Arsenal': [{'number': '1',
               'position': 'Goalkeeper',
               'name': 'Bernd Leno'},
              {'number': '26',
               'position': 'Goalkeeper',
               'name': 'Emiliano Martínez'},
              {'number': '33', 'position': 'Goalkeeper', 'name': 'Matt Macey'},
              {'number': '2',
               'position': 'Defender',
               'name': 'Héctor Bellerín'},
                 .......................
```

Comment: I see, since I can't make `players[team_name] = dict(zip(key_number,v_number))` etc.. work, do you perhaps recommend a specific method? Thank you for your input!

Comment: you can use a list to store your data, if is ok for  you : `list(zip(number, name, position))`

Comment: I will try that, see if works the way I intend. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: also will work: `[{'number': num, 'name': n, 'position': p} for num, n, p in zip(number, name, position)]` this approach is a bit more explicit

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe something is wrong with my indentation, since only the last element gets appended to each `team_name`. Otherwise your solution should be working!

Comment: You should use as key for dict players : f'{team_name}-{i}'

Comment: players[f'{team_name}-{i}'}]

Comment: Haven't seen that method before, unfortunately the problem remains when I tried it! Thank you for trying to help

Comment: you have many other problems when you parse, but I guess I answered your question

Comment: @MisterButter check now, I have also posted the output